# Render React Component Depending on its Type

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-proptypes, react-component

I was wondering if there was a way, in React, to conditionally render components based on their type. According to the documentation, you can define the a component's prop types in the following way:

```
MyComponent.propTypes = {
  description: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.string, PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.string)]),
};
```

Is there a way, using the framework to check for the type and render a component differently depending on whether the received prop data is a `string` or `array`?

I know I can use raw JS to determine this, by using `type of` or checking for properties of an array on the data.

```
if (typeof description === "string") { /* render string component */ }
else { /* render array component */ }
```

I was wondering if React, had a built-in, more robust method of doing this.